# on buttonclick check if file exist then prompt message and revert

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a scenario where I want to check if user adds data with `same date` and `same region` again, it should give him a prompt alert.

I tried this with code behind,like below:-

```
 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
    dtExcel.Clear();
    string StrCount = String.Empty;
    string connString = "";
    HttpPostedFile File = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
    string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower();
    string path = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    string Filename = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1, path.Length - path.LastIndexOf("\\") - 1);
    path = Server.MapPath(@"~/Excels/" + "/" + Filename.ToString());

    File.SaveAs(path);
    if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
    {
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }
    else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
    {
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }
    string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet 1$]";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    conn.Close();
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter daExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

    daExcel.Fill(dtExcel);
    conn.Close();


    DataTable DtMain = CF.ExecuteDT("select Tran_type, Order_Date, Region_Mkey from WMS_Future_Del_Order_Hdr where Tran_type = '" + CmbTypeOfAsn.SelectedValue + "' and Order_Date = convert(datetime,'" + TxtEdate.Value + "',103) and Region_Mkey = '" + ddlRegion.SelectedValue + "'"); // checks the duplicate records here


    if (DtMain.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessScript", "myTestFunction()", true);  
    }
```

Also see my function for prompting the alert for duplicate message

```
function myTestFunction() {
         if (confirm('Are you sure you want to override the file ?')) {
             return true;
         }
         else {
             return false;
         }
     }
```

but what happens here is even after cancel click, the excel file is uploaded and gets saved. I dont know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although *Abbas Kapasi's* solution based on AJAX is good one (and you do not want to/can not use the solution based on CheckBox as I suggested in my other post [codebhind-javascript-alert-for-yes-and-no-not-working-exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33477274/5104101)), if you are not familiar with AJAX or don't want to use AJAX then you may achieve it using following approach. It may seem a bit odd but you may modify it according to your requirements:

1. I am splitting the code to upload and find existing file/record in one procedure and the code to write/overwrite the records in another sub-procedure.
2. Then I am using two LinkButtons, `LinkButtonLoad` and `LinkButtonOverwrite`.
   `LinkButtonLoad` will be attached to the call the main procedure which uploads and finds existing file/record. `LinkButtonOverwrite` will call the procedure to write/overwrite the records. *LinkButtonOverwrite will remain **hidden** from the user*.
3. In the first procedure if the system finds existing file/record it will show a client side prompt to the user to overwrite or not. If the file/record does not exist it will call second sub-procedure to write the records.
4. On client side, if the prompt is displayed for existing file/record and the user selects `Cancel/No` the process will not proceed. If the user selects `OK/Yes` then I'll be calling the procedure linked to the LinkButton2 to overwrite the records.

Now putting it all together:

In aspx/front end

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonLoad" runat="server" Text="Load Records" CssClass="button" ... />
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonOverwrite" runat="server" Text="ow" CssClass="button hidden" ... />
```

I'm using `hidden` CSS class to hide the button `.hidden {display: none;}`. Do NOT use `visible="false"` attribute, it'll not be available on the client side.

JavaScript on client side:

```
function myTestFunction() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to override the file ?')) {
        // get the action attribute of the hidden LinkButtonOverwrite here and call it on OK
        // as an alternative you may also invoke the click event of this button
        var defaultAction = $('#<%=LinkButtonOverwrite.ClientID %>').prop("href");
        window.location.href = defaultAction;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

LinkButtonLoad in code behind:

```
protected void LinkButtonLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //==============================================================
    // YOUR CODE TO UPLOAD THE FILE, SAVE IT SO WE MAY USE IT AGAIN
    //==============================================================
    if (DtMain.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessScript", "myTestFunction()", true);
    }
    else
    {
        MySubToOverwrite();
    }
}
```

LinkButtonOverwrite in code behind:

```
protected void LinkButtonOverwrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //===========================================================
    // AS THE FILE IS ALREADY UPLOADED IN LINKBUTTONUPLOAD_CLICK
    // YOU MAY ACCESS IT AND PERFORM REQUIRED OPERATIONS
    //===========================================================

    MySubToOverwrite();
}
```

MySubToOverwrite() code in behind:

```
private void MySubToOverwrite()
{
    //==========================================================
    // OVERWRITE YOUR RECORDS HERE
    // FROM THE FILE ALREADY UPLOADED IN LINKBUTTONUPLOAD_CLICK
    //==========================================================
}
```

Comment: @coder Seems like you are still stuck on Yes/No. Check this solution, if it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Detecting duplicate records**

There are a few ways you can do this. Just going to touch on the big picture here, in order of my personal preference:

1. Easiest method: **Don't check. Prompt first.** Provide a checkbox up front. [image]
2. Use 2 Ajax requests: one to check for existing record, and another to save the file (if user said "OK" or if file not yet exists). Challenge: multiuser environments.
3. Multi-step POST back. Server code injects a dynamic control (or shows a hidden static one) that prompts user to overwrite. Ugly, but does not require  JS. You may remember this from the '90s.
4. **Versioning**: more advanced, more complex, but for Enterprise systems this is the way to go. Do not overwrite files with same identifier; store a different version of it. Then you get a nice history and audit trail of who changed it. Makes it easy to go back to fix mistakes, blame people, etc.

**Canceling the PostBack** (if using option 3 or other postback method)

You need to bind to the correct button, and to prevent POST to the server (AKA "postback") you must `return false` in either

- the `click` event handler of the rendered `input type="button"`

  or
- the `submit` event handler if the `form`

You can accomplish this by embedding the return value to `myTestFunction()` in the `asp:Button` itself:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save"
  OnClientClick="if(!myTestFunction()){return false;}" 
  OnClick="btnSave_Click" />

<script>
  function myTestFunction() {
      return confirm('Override the file?');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use ajax function with webservice to check the same data and region

Submit button code

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnupload" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript return checkData()"
                                        Text="Upload" OnClick="btnupload_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Javacript

```
<script>

function checkData() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "demo.aspx/functionName1",
                data: "{parameter1:'" + param1 "',parameter2:'" + param2 + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                   if(msg.d == 'Yes'){
                       if (confirm('Are you sure you want to override the file ?')) {
                                return true;
                           }
                          else {
                                return false;
                         }
                    }
                    else{
                         return true;
                   }
                }
            });
        }


</script>
```

C# Code

```
using System.Web.Services; --- use this class

   [WebMethod]
        public static string functionName1(string parameter1, string parameter2)
        {

            ------------------------------;

           if(check Condition)
            return "Yes";
           else
            return "No"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In reality, you just need the following to make it work. Use `RegisterOnSubmitStatement` instead of `RegisterStartupScript`. It would let you add script that executes in response to the button's `onclick` event. The script is executed before the button event is invoked, and gives you an opportunity to cancel the event.

**`Code-behind:`**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // You can place this in any method where you want to do the validation. 
   String scriptText =
       "return confirm('Are you sure you want to override the file ?')";
        ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(),
            "ConfirmSubmit", scriptText);
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

**`Markup :`**

```
<asp:Button id="ConfirmSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click"/>
```