# Codebhind javascript alert for YES and NO not working exactly

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have written confirmation message for YES and NO.
Here is the code:-

```
 function myTestFunction() {
         if (confirm('Are you sure you want to override the file ?')) {
             return true;
         }
         else {
             return false;
         }
     }
```

Also see the code behind:-

```
 if (DtMain.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessScript", "myTestFunction()", true);
    }
```

Now my issue is that, when i click NO, it still moves ahead and the data is getting saved. what is going wrong here

**UPDATED CODE**

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
    dtExcel.Clear();
    string StrCount = String.Empty;
    string connString = "";
    HttpPostedFile File = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
    string strFileType = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName).ToLower();
    string path = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
    string Filename = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1, path.Length - path.LastIndexOf("\\") - 1);
    path = Server.MapPath(@"~/Excels/" + "/" + Filename.ToString());

    File.SaveAs(path);
    if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xls")
    {
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }
    else if (strFileType.Trim() == ".xlsx")
    {
        connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
    }
    string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet 1$]";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    conn.Close();
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        conn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
    OleDbDataAdapter daExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

    daExcel.Fill(dtExcel);
    conn.Close();

    DataTable DtMain = CF.ExecuteDT("select Tran_type, Order_Date, Region_Mkey from WMS_Future_Del_Order_Hdr where Tran_type = '" + CmbTypeOfAsn.SelectedValue + "' and Order_Date = convert(datetime,'" + TxtEdate.Value + "',103) and Region_Mkey = '" + ddlRegion.SelectedValue + "'");

    if (DtMain.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessScript", "myTestFunction()", true);
    }

    StringBuilder StrPubBldg = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(StrPubBldg);

    string ExcelfileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

    xw.WriteStartElement("DocumentElement");
    {
        xw.WriteStartElement("WMS_Future_Del_Order_Hdr");
        xw.WriteElementString("Comp_mkey", "0");
        xw.WriteElementString("FDepartment_ID", "W");
        xw.WriteElementString("FModule_id", "W");
        xw.WriteElementString("Tran_type", CmbTypeOfAsn.SelectedValue);
        xw.WriteElementString("Doc_no", "1");
        xw.WriteElementString("Doc_date", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        xw.WriteElementString("Order_Date", TxtEdate.Value);
        xw.WriteElementString("Import_Filename", Filename);
        xw.WriteElementString("Save_File_Name_Path", Server.MapPath("~/FutureDelivery/") + ExcelfileName + ".xls");
        xw.WriteElementString("Note_Remarks", txtRemarks.Text);
        xw.WriteElementString("User_id", "1");
        xw.WriteElementString("U_DateTime", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
        xw.WriteElementString("Delete_flag", "N");
        xw.WriteEndElement();

        string STRLine_Id = "0";
        string STRItem_Mkey = "1";
        string STRItem_Code = "2";
        string STRItem_Desc = "3";
        string STRLot_Batch_No = "4";
        string STRExp_Dt = "";
        string STRBx_Bg = "6";
        string STRNet_Wgt = "7";
        string STRQty = "8";
        string STRNo_of_Pallets = "9";
        DataTable ParaDt = CF.ExecuteDT("select * from WMS_Mapping_Para_Table");
        for (int i = 0; i < ParaDt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Line_Id")
            {
                STRLine_Id = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }
            else if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Item_Mkey")
            {
                STRItem_Mkey = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }
            else if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Item_Code")
            {
                STRItem_Code = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }
            else if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Item_Desc")
            {
                STRItem_Desc = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }
            else if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Lot_Batch_No")
            {
                STRLot_Batch_No = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }
            else if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Exp_Dt")
            {
                STRExp_Dt = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }
            else if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Qty")
            {
                STRQty = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }
            else if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Bx_Bg")
            {
                STRBx_Bg = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }
            else if (ParaDt.Rows[i]["Txn_Column_Name"].ToString() == "Net_Wgt")
            {
                STRNet_Wgt = ParaDt.Rows[i]["Sheet_Int_Id"].ToString();
            }

        }
        if (dtExcel.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dtExcel.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                xw.WriteStartElement("WMS_Future_Del_Order_Trl");
                xw.WriteElementString("Sr_No", (i + 1).ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Line_Id", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRLine_Id)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Item_Mkey", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRItem_Mkey)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Item_Code", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRItem_Code)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Item_Desc", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRItem_Desc)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Lot_Batch_No", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRLot_Batch_No)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Exp_Dt", Convert.ToDateTime(dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRExp_Dt)].ToString()).ToShortDateString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Qty", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRQty)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Bx_Bg", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRBx_Bg)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Net_Wgt", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRNet_Wgt)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("No_of_Pallets", dtExcel.Rows[i][Convert.ToInt32(STRNo_of_Pallets)].ToString());
                xw.WriteElementString("Creation_Date", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
                xw.WriteElementString("Update_Date", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
                xw.WriteElementString("Created_By", "1");
                xw.WriteElementString("Updated_By", "1");
                xw.WriteElementString("User_id", "1");
                xw.WriteElementString("U_DateTime", System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
                xw.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
        xw.Close();
        String strretmkey = InsertUpdateDelete.InsertUpdateDeleteCls.InsertUpdateDelete_sql(Hid_Mode.Value, Convert.ToInt32(Hid_MKey.Value), "WMS_Future_Del_Order_Hdr", "MKEY", "FD", StrPubBldg.ToString());
        DataTable dt = CF.ExecuteDT("Select Tran_type,DATEPART(yyyy,U_DateTime) AS U_DateTime,DATEPART(mm,U_DateTime) AS U_DateTime from WMS_Future_Del_Order_Hdr where mkey ='" + strretmkey + "'");
        StrDocNo = strretmkey + '/' + dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() + '/' + dt.Rows[0][2].ToString() + dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();

        ExcelfileName = StrDocNo.ToString().Replace("/", "_");
        string strPathval = Server.MapPath("~/FutureDelivery/") + ExcelfileName + ".xls";
        FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/FutureDelivery/") + ExcelfileName + ".xls");

        CF.ExecuteQuerry("update WMS_Future_Del_Order_Hdr set Doc_no ='" + StrDocNo + "', Save_File_Name_Path ='" + strPathval + "' where mkey=" + strretmkey + "");

        lblDocNo.Text = StrDocNo.ToString();
        Hid_MKey.Value = strretmkey;
    }

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessScript", "alert('Record saved successfully.');", true);
    FunGridBind();

    btnSave.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Is the `RegisterStartupScript` part of the code that performs the data update? A client-side script will not stop the execution of your server-side logic in this case. You should display the prompt before passing data from client to the server.

Comment: You are not using the value returned from the JavaScript function. You would either put that value somewhere where it will be included in the next postback, or send it back to the server using AJAX (or similar). When the server gets that value, it can determine what to do with it. If you want to avoid this extra round trip to the server, you would show the `confirm` before the form is posted back the first time.

Comment: @Guffa: how to do that sir ??

Comment: @pawel: yes sir, it is inserting the data before  calling the function itself

Comment: This functionality can not be achieved without multiple/multi-step form/ajax workflow. However, one simplest approach you may think of is, you provide an additional checkbox or similar control in the user input which prompts the user to whether overwrite existing file or not and then on btnSave check the value (checked state) of that checkbox and take action accordingly.

Comment: @haraman: but before checking the checkbox, the condition may vary. it depends on the date and region which he adds. It checks first then it prompts.

Comment: The basic idea is to confirm in advance that if such record exists whether overwrite or not. Otherwise it should be performed in a multi-form/ajax way.

Comment: @haraman: how to confirm it before ??

Comment: Place a checkbox like "Overwrite existing record" just before your btnSave in aspx, then on btnSave_Click event check if record/file exists, if record exists then check value of your overwrite checkbox, if it is selected then overwrite the record otherwise just prompt the user that record exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93971/discussion-between-coder-and-haraman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can not mix server side code execution with client side code this way. So as per discussion this can be achieved using following two approaches.

**Approach 1: Using a CheckBox**

Place a CheckBox on your aspx/front end such as this

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkOverwriteFile" runat="server" Text="Overwrite existing file" />
```

Then use it on code behind on your `btnSave.Click` event as below

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //////////////////// YOUR OTHER CODE

    DataTable DtMain = CF.ExecuteDT("select Tran_type, Order_Date, Region_Mkey from WMS_Future_Del_Order_Hdr where Tran_type = '" + CmbTypeOfAsn.SelectedValue + "' and Order_Date = convert(datetime,'" + TxtEdate.Value + "',103) and Region_Mkey = '" + ddlRegion.SelectedValue + "'");

    bool blWriteReecord = false;
    if (DtMain.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (chkOverwriteFile.Checked) {
            blWriteReecord = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "SuccessScript", "alert('Record already exitst. If you want to overwrite it then select Overwrite existing file and then save again.');", true);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        blWriteReecord = true;
    }

    if (blWriteReecord) {
        StringBuilder StrPubBldg = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        ///////////////// YOUR OTHER CODE

        FunGridBind();

        btnSave.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

The code block will check for the already existing file/records. If it exists then it will ask the user to select the CheckBox to overwrite the records.

Then the user selects the checkbox and submits again. It is just an alternative for Yes/No confirm messagebox as select checkbox or not.

Moreover if you want to extend it then you can initially hide the checkbox and display only if the record exists.

**Approach 2: Using a hidden div**

In this approach you can follow these steps:

1. Along with your `FileUpload` and `btnSave` you include a hidden message div on the front end designed similarly to a MessageBox containing your message and two buttons for `Yes`(btnYes, server side for calling code behind or client side if you want to use AJAX) and `No`. (This message div can be CSS/JavaScript based or as per your convenience or framework)
2. On your `btnSave.Click` you check your file/records and normally save it if it does not exist. If it does exist already then you invoke the hidden div from code behind prompting to overwrite or not.
3. If the user select `No` just hide the message div and do nothing.
4. If the user selects `Yes` call the same code as in `btnSave.Click` but do not prompt the user for existing file/record, just overwrite it.
5. To avoid repetition the code may be re-organised into sub parts i.e. functions/subs which can be called from both `btnSave.Click` as well as `Yes` button of message div, with additional parameter which decides whether to overwrite the file or show the message div.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is happening with the return value of your function, it is just called once your page is loaded, and that's it. You should do something with it.

Also, it appears that the question is presented to the user when the action has already been performed.

So you should go to the HTML page where you have the form that is being submitted (or similar action) which triggers the action. There you should put something like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to override the file ?')"
      action=... >
```

Also note that your function was unnecessary long. It translates `true` to `true` and `false` to `false`. You can just return the value of `confirm`.
The `onsubmit` attribute can be used to validate a form, and if its value is false, the form will not be submitted; the user stays on the page.

Comment: well then you should ask this question on the page where the submission takes place. Could you extend your original question and supply the HTML form where you let the user submit his request?

Comment: i dont want on direct button click, it should first check the condition. If there is something which is duplicate then it should override. In your case it is happening directly on button click

Comment: If you are checking the conditions on the server side, then you need to redesign the workflow. You cannot do the update in the same step as checking these conditions, you need to show another page first to the user where you ask for confirmation, and only when that answer is posted back to the server, you can proceed with the update. It seems that you are now doing both in one action, and the user has no way to half-way confirm. You need to break it up.

Comment: any idea on how to proceed this??

Comment: In your ASP, at the point where you know the conditions are such that the user should get a chance to confirm, don't proceed with the update, but instead generate an HTML page where the user can submit their OK. Then on that submit you will have another ASP code that will do the update. It should be in two different steps. You should now go and try this. We cannot write your whole project for you.