# how can we trigger confirmation box from aspx from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I'm trying to trigger confirmation box from server side after doing some server side validations..

```
<asp:button id="btnSumbit" runat="server" text="Submit" onclick="test()" />

server side:

public void test()
{  
//DO some business validations to make sure user inputted data is correct..if data is correct prompt for confirmation box

if(data is correct) 
{
COnfirm("are you sure you want to submit(Y/N)")
if(Y)
save data;

else return to the page;
}
else show data error

}
```

Currently we have an aspx page which is designed as confirmation box and we are calling it from javascript using `window.showmodaldialog` upon clicking the submit button but due to some business requirement we need to do some validations on the data at server side before displaying confirmation box so we have to move the trigger of confirmation box to code behind.
Just wondering is there any way to achieve this..Please help!!!

Comment: can u do everything in an ajax call? [webmethod]

Comment: Have a look at [on buttonclick check if file exist then prompt message](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33618550/5104101) and also [Codebhind javascript alert for YES and NO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33477274/5104101)